# Unexpected behaviour: italic() causing cut-off of two-line axis label in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Use of italics (`italic()`) in a y-axis label that goes over two lines in ggplot is causing the first line to be partly cut off.

E.g.

```
ggplot() +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 1)) +
  labs(y = expression(paste("Something\nsomething", italic(x'))))
```

[image]

There's no reason apparent this should be happening — the same thing doesn't happen with very similar code not using `italic()`, e.g. using `hat()` instead:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 1)) +
  labs(y = expression(paste("Something\nsomething", hat(x))))
```

[image]

Anyone know why this would occur or what to do about it, other than tedious manual altering plot and margin sizes or such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why this happens but you can increase the plot margins within `ggplot2`...

```
ggplot() +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 1)) +
  labs(y = expression(paste("Something\nsomething", hat(x)))) +
  theme(plot.margin=unit(c(1,1,1,1), "cm"))
```

Comment: Thanks, answer works fine. It's sub-optimal though, as that sort of fiddling is something I'd rather avoid -  I'd rather address what's actually causing the odd behaviour.

Comment: I have the same opinion, but I couldn't figure out the problem and used this fix in similar problems with bigger axis labels etc.